How to call a function / Robotframework Keyword when appium detects a particular page
I am currently running android mobile applications tests with appium, Robotframework and Python.
Scenario: A new feature has been implemented - App Pin. This page would show up after X seconds soon after the app opens. Now I need to adapt this new feature to all my existing test cases.
One way I can think is, Create a custom Robotframework keyword for app pin and use it where ever necessary. One thing I dont like about this approach is that I will be hardcoding the keyword according to the timing the App pin page is being showed up.
I was wondering if there is any other approach such that if appium itself detects that page, the keyword is called in?
Please let me know. Thank you!

Hi @Shetty, maybe Appium keywords like Wait Until Element Is Visible (or any other keywords starting with Wait Until) is something you are looking for? Flow would be Open Application -> Wait Until Element (related to PIN code) Is Visible -> Custom Input PIN Code keyword.

On "pure" selenium side, selenium offers EventFiringWebDriver. It allows before and after events to be triggered in most cases "before" and "after" your code interacts in any way with the SUT.   While those events that EventFiringWebDriver supports are not 100% perfect for all use cases, if you are capable dev or have one on the team, thats where i would start to look at.

And reason why i mentioned above, at least java side of Appium does mention a support for event firing stuff so, quite sure it could be useful for python / rf side of things with a bit of development effort.
